# Clean url need by .htaccess & multiple Rewrite Rule use smoothly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting

There is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

#This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ single.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ categories.php?x=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ subcat.php?q=$1&ccsn=$2 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

#This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And want to doing like href link according to make Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ single.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
<a href="single/555">Link Name</a>

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ categories.php?x=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
<a href="categories/apple">Apple</a>


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ subcat.php?q=$1&ccsn=$2 [NC,L]
<a href="subcat/paper">Product</a>

<a href="paper">Paper</a>
<a href="items">items</a>
```

Why these rule are not work perfectly? I want to do multiple Rewrite Rule work perfectly.

```
#This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ single.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ categories.php?x=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ subcat.php?q=$1&ccsn=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your htaccess file. Could you please do mention FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect? Also your rules are looking same(so how its going to match all conditions of all urls?). That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Trying to match the exact same patterns in multiple places, that makes zero sense to begin with. Your server has no way of differentiating, which “case” you meant this to be in each instance. You want to match different URL patterns here, that start with static keywords, `single`, `categories`, `subcat` - so start by writing rules that incorporate these prefixes.

Comment: As a first post of yours @Mohamed RIB, you have made Good attempt of posting your question nicely(by posting your efforts in your question). If you could answer of questions mentioned in previous 2 comments then you will certainly get more help/guidance on this one, thank you.

Comment: Kindly make right Rewrite Rule according to on my .htaccess Rewrite Rules, Thanks for your cooperation...

Comment: Try to fix these issue: #This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ single.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ categories.php?x=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule not work 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ subcat.php?q=$1&ccsn=$2 [NC,L]

#This rule work perfect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: Please don’t ask us to fix your issue, while you are still ignoring the feedback you have already gotten. It makes _no sense whatsoever_, to use the exact same pattern multiple times - and then expect the server would know, which of the three to choose.